# One legend entry when plotting several curves using one `plot` call

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a grid by plotting several curves using one `plot` call as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.array([[0,1], [0,1], [0,1]])
y = np.array([[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]])

ax.plot([0,1],[0,2], label='foo', color='b')

ax.plot(x.T, y.T, label='bar', color='k')

ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

The resulting legend has as many 'bar' entries as there are curves (see below). I wish that have only one legend entry per `plot` call (in this case only one time 'bar').

I want this such that I can have other plot commands (e.g. the one plotting the 'foo' curve) whose curves are *automatically* included in the legend if they have a label. I specifically want to avoid hand-selecting the handles when constructing the legend, but rather use matplotlib's feature to deal with this by yes/no including a label when plotting.  How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one possible solution: You may use the fact that underscores do not produce legend entries. So setting all but the first label to `"_"` suppresses those to appear in the legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.array([[0,1], [0,1], [0,1]])
y = np.array([[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]])

ax.plot([0,1],[0,2], label='foo', color='b')

lines = ax.plot(x.T, y.T, label='bar', color='k')
plt.setp(lines[1:], label="_")
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Following is one way using the already existing legend handles and labels. You first get the three `handles, labels` and then just show the first one. This way **additionally** gives you a control **not only** on the order of putting handles **but also** what to show on the plot.

```
ax.plot(x.T, y.T,  label='bar', color='k')
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend([handles[0]], [labels[0]], loc='best')
```

[image]

**Alternative approach** where the legends will **only** be taken from a particular plot (set of lines) -- `ax1` in this case

```
ax1 = ax.plot(x.T, y.T,  label='bar', color='k')
plt.legend(handles=[ax1[0]], loc='best')
```

Extending it to you problem with two figures

```
ax1 = ax.plot([0,1],[0,2], label='foo', color='b')
ax2 = ax.plot(x.T, y.T,  label='bar', color='k')
plt.legend(handles=[ax1[0], ax2[1]], loc='best')
```

Another alternative using for loops as suggested by @SpghttCd

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    ax.plot(x[i], y[i], label=('' if i==0 else '_') + 'bar', color='k')

ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. A disadvantage I see is that this would break that `legend` automatically gets the handles from other plot commands that were given a label. Right?

Comment: I didn't understand your point. Could you perhaps rephrase? If you have other curves plotted on the same axes `ax`, this would then not work. But for your current problem, it looks straightforward.

Comment: I added a second approach where the other plot commands won't be considered for legends because now you take them **only** from a particular plot, `ax1` in this case

Comment: I see, sorry for being not fully clear. I have rephrased the question to make more clear that, and why, I wish to avoid carrying handles.

Comment: You can use `label=None` in the second plot command but then you will at some point of time add 'bar' back again to the existing legend. I don't think there is any direct way to just say that include only one legend in the `ax.plot()` command

Comment: I just added an extended work-around solution for your foo and bar cases. Maybe it helps you

Comment: I'm not too deep in your conversation here, but it might be worth noting, that you can surpress labels showing up in the legend by adding an underline as first character of the label (e.g. label='_foo'). That means you could progammatically add those underlines to labels e.g. perhaps in a loop depending on the counter (let's say `i`), so that only the first iteration will create a label for the legend: `ax.plot(x.T, y.T, label=('' if i==0 else '_') + 'bar', color='k')`

Comment: @SpghttCd: You are right, I thought of this loop based solution first but I wasn't sure if the OP wanted for loops. Let me put your solution as an edit in mine with proper acknowledgement. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What would be the most need is use a counter internal to `plot` and provide a `lambda` function to act on it in this way. With the loop as it is given one can wonder whether it is not equally easy to suppress the `label` option altogether based on the counter (a matter of style of course). @SpghttCd

Comment: @TomdeGeus: You can use two plot commands in the for loop using an if statement. `If i==0: plt.plot(.... label='bar') else: plt.plot(....)`. But it's a matter of taste. I really like SpghttCd's solution. After all it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not quite elegant, but the easiest and most straightforward way is to make a second plot using a single pair of elements where you prescribe the 'label' you want!

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.array([[0,1], [0,1], [0,1]])
y = np.array([[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]])

ax.plot([0,1],[0,2], label='foo', color='b')

ax.plot(x.T, y.T, color='k')
ax.plot(x[0].T, y[0].T, label='bar', color='k')


ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]