# Legend displayed only for a subset of curves in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to do what has been explained for MATLAB here:
[How to show legend for only a specific subset of curves in the plotting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685967/how-to-show-legend-for-only-a-specific-subset-of-curves-in-the-plotting)

But using Python instead of MATLAB.

Brief summary of my goal: when plotting for example three curves in the following way

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
c=[7,8,9]
# these are the curves
plt.plot(a)
plt.plot(b)
plt.plot(c)
plt.legend(['a','nothing','c'])
plt.show()
```

Instead of the word "nothing", I would like not to have anything there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `'_'` will suppress the legend for a particular entry as following (continue reading for handling underscore `_` as a legend). This solution is motivated by the recent post of @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497476/one-legend-entry-when-plotting-several-curves-using-one-plot-call).

```
plt.legend(['a','_','c'])
```

I would also avoid the way you are putting legends right now because in this way, you have to **make sure** that the plot commands are in the same order as legend. Rather, put the `label` in the respective plot commands to avoid errors.

That being said, the straightforward and easiest solution (in my opinion) is to do the following

```
plt.plot(a, label='a')
plt.plot(b)
plt.plot(c, label='c')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

As @Lucas pointed out in comment, if you want to show an underscore `_` as the label for plot b, how would you do it. You can do it using

```
plt.legend(['a','$\_$','c'])
```

[image]

Comment: What if you want to name your plot `_` literaly?

Comment: Do you mean `_ = plt.plot(b)` and then `plt.legend(['a','_','c'])`. It works in that case too although you get a user warning. That's why the second method I wrote is the way to go

Comment: I think he meant that he might want to have the low bar in the legend, like naming a curve 'e_4'

Comment: No, that's not what he meant because you can easily do `plt.legend(['a_4','','c'])`

Comment: Yes, naming the curve `_` only, like: `plt.plot(a, label='_')`  Is there any way to show that legend?

Comment: @Lucas: Yes, you can do it as `plt.legend(['a','$\_$','c'])`. I added your suggestion in my answer

Comment: Who downvoted you? You provided a precise, complete and clear answer.